# Использование вложенных маршрутов в React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

1. Для организации маршрутов в приложении использую React Router.

   ```
   <Route path="/" component={...}>
       <IndexRoute component={...}/>
       <Route path="user/:userId" component={...}>
           <Route path="settings" component={...}/>
       </Route>
   </Route>
   ```
2. Когда открываю корневой маршрут (`http://localhost/`) проблем не возникает.
3. Когда же открываю маршрут `http://localhost/user/1` или `http://localhost/user/1/settings` то получаю ошибку `Unexpected token <`, при этом stack trace пустой.
4. Если открыть маршрут `http://localhost/user/1` или `http://localhost/user/1/settings` с помощью Link (из react-router) то они открывается без проблем.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы указать версию роутера? Они часто ломали обратную совместимость